# How to print hidden table in HTML?

Tags: html, css, printing, css-tables

I have two tables on HTML page. One is Visible on screen and second is hidden using CSS. I want to print the hidden table.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Create a print.css style sheet and set the table to visible there.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a print stylesheet and set the `display` property to `table`:

On the page you wish to print the table, add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/path/to/print.css" type="text/css" />
```

And then inside `print.css`, add:

```
table { 
    display: table; 
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use External CSS. Is there any way using inline CSS to printing a hidden table?

Comment: No. Inlining CSS is a really bad practice in the main. Why don't you want to use external CSS?

Comment: I think if External CSS can do, then inline also support that functionality. And i have only 1 page with 2 table only and i have to complete this printing using 1 file(HTML file) only.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="printPage">Print</a> 
<table id="tblprint" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <tr>
      <td>Print Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script lang='javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#printPage').click(function(){
        var data = '<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">';           
        data += '<div id="div_print">';
        data += $('#tblprint').html();
        data += '</div>';

        myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
        myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
        myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
        myWindow.screenX = 0;
        myWindow.screenY = 0;
        myWindow.document.write(data);
        myWindow.focus();
    });
 });
</script>
```